# Is that real vs Really

Tags: colloquial-language, exclamatives

> Is that real.
>
> Really.

When you hear a unbelievable thing, can I say both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Really?" or "Oh, really?" seems more idiomatic. It is used to express astonished disbelief or sarcasm.

> Heat is work and work's a curse
>   And all the heat in the Universe
>   Is gonna cooool down 'cos it can't increase
>   Then there'll be no more work and there'll be perfect peace
>   **Really?**
>   Yeah - that's entropy, man!

(I guess the tone of voice is important in imparting the phrase this or that meaning.)

"Is that real?" seems to lack the preposition "for":

> Is that **for** real?

Or, rather:

> Are you for real?